# How to end call prematurely in Twilio via callSid?

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

In my Java application I have functionality that ends call made via Twilio by callSid. I'm using this code:

```
Call.updater(callSid).setStatus(Call.UpdateStatus.COMPLETED).update();
```

However, when I start the call and then end it before the call comes to the phone (before ringing is started) it doesn't end properly. The call comes to the phone and it keeps ringing until I accept the call and after this it immediately ends. Only when I end the call after the phone starts ringing it ends without me having to accept it.
Is there a way to end call properly before it reaches the phone?

Answer (score 0):

If this is call is initiated by a Dial verb, you must modify the Parent Call SID to impact the Child Call if it has not been answered.

[Call Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call)

"Unanswered child calls cannot be canceled via the REST API, but the parent call can be modified to point to new TwiML. This action will end the child call."